# Grails switching config properties based on another property loaded from a file

Tags: grails, spring-security, configuration-files

I'm not sure if this is possible or if I'm gonna have to find another way around it but...

I have a Grails application that uses Spring-Security-Core as its authentication system. There are a few locations where it may eventually be deployed and different locations may use different authentication providers (e.g some will use DAO, some with use LDAP etc.)

I want to be able to set up the app based on a line in a .properties file 'auth.type=LDAP' or 'auth.type=DAO'. Once the app knows which of the two it will be it then needs to set further properties withing Config.groovy in order to cater for this.

I was thinking along the lines of needing config.groovy to load the properties from the .properties file and then within Config.groovy use those properties in a switch statement to determines which other properties to set. However I tried this, but I believe that in the Config file, properties from a .properties file are loaded in after all properties in the config file. Is that a correct assumption?

Anyway if anyone knows of a simple way to achieve this affect, would be very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that properties read from `grails.config.locations` files (groovy or properties) are only applied after the main `Config.groovy` has been read.  You could use custom environments, and have stuff like

```
environments {
  ldapAuth {
    foo.bar = 'something'
  }
  daoAuth {
    foo.bar = 'something else'
  }
}
```

but you have to specify the environment when you build the WAR, you can't build one WAR and then configure it for a different environment at runtime.

If you have some way to specify system properties to the tomcat (or whatever) that is running your WAR then you could do something like

```
def authType = System.getProperty('myapp.auth.type', 'dao')
// store authType as a real config option as well as a local variable
auth.type = authType

switch(authType) {
  case 'dao':
    foo {
      bar = 'something'
    }
    break

  case 'ldap':
    foo {
      bar = 'something else'
    }
    break

  default:
    println "Unrecognised auth type ${authType}"
}
```

Or manually read a `.properties` file yourself (rather than relying on `grails.config.locations`)

```
def authProps = new Properties()
new File('/etc/myapp/auth.properties').withInputStream(authProps.&load)
def authType = authProps.getProperty('auth.type', 'dao')
auth.type = authType

// switch(authType) as before
```

One wrinkle - within the `log4j` closure you may find you can't access the `authProps` variable (I don't know, I haven't tried it).  However inside that closure you *can* access the complete configuration as `config`, so provided you have the `auth.type = authType` line I've used above you can just say `config.auth.type` instead.